How do I modify the formatting of an excel worksheet without overwriting any existing formatting styles using openpyxl
I'm trying to build easy to use functions that can be applied to excel sheets on top of openpyxl. But what I noticed is that anytime I apply formatting to a cell, any previous formatting is reverted.
So for example if I have a column that's already bold, and I want to make it underlined, if I don't explicitly say "make it bold again" along with "make it underlined", it won't be bold anymore.
Here's some code that I have. Can someone help me? There's gotta be a way to maintain existing formatting, or at the very least extract out existing formatting and reapply it.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, PatternFill, Border, Side


def bold_italic(wb, ws, path, rows=None, cols=None, bold=False, italic=False):

    font_together = Font(bold=bold, italic=italic)

    #Function for applying formatting
    def apply_format(cell_range):
        for row in cell_range:
            for cell in row:
                cell.font = font_together
    
    if rows:
        if isinstance(rows, int):
            apply_format(ws.iter_rows(min_row=rows, max_row=rows))
        elif isinstance(rows, list):
            for row in rows:
                apply_format(ws.iter_rows(min_row=row, max_row=row))
    if cols:
        if isinstance(cols, int):
            apply_format(ws.iter_cols(min_col=cols, max_col=cols))
        elif isinstance(cols, list):
            for col in cols:
                apply_format(ws.iter_cols(min_col=col, max_col=col))

    wb.save(path)


def font_size_color(wb, ws, path, rows=None, cols=None,font_name=None, font_size=None, font_color=None):
    
    font_together = Font(name=font_name, size=font_size, color=font_color)

    # Function to apply font formatting
    def apply_font(cell_range):
        for row in cell_range:
            for cell in row:
                cell.font = font_together

    if rows:
        if isinstance(rows, int):
            apply_font(ws.iter_rows(min_row=rows, max_row=rows))
        elif isinstance(rows, list):
            for row in rows:
                apply_font(ws.iter_rows(min_row=row, max_row=row))
    if cols:
        if isinstance(cols, int):
            apply_font(ws.iter_cols(min_col=cols, max_col=cols))
        elif isinstance(cols, list):
            for col in cols:
                apply_font(ws.iter_cols(min_col=col, max_col=col))

    # Save the workbook
    wb.save(path)


path = 'Book.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook['SHEET_1']

bold_italic(workbook,worksheet, path,rows=2,cols=[2,3],bold=True)
font_size_color(workbook,worksheet, path,rows=1,cols=[2,3],font_name='Arial',font_size=12, font_color = "FF0000")

In the code above, if you run it, the end result will have columns 2 and 3 not bold, because of the second function call which changes the font, size and color of the text.

I don't know your exact use case, but it seems you can combine the 2 functions into 1

As you're assigning new font objects all time, what do you expect? You can combine format objects: cell.font = cell.font + ft2

You can read the formatting before modifying it as such :
def modify_font(wb, ws, pth, rows=None, cols=None, 
                bold=None, italic=None, font_name=None, font_size=None, font_color=None):

    def apply_font(cell_range):
        for row in cell_range:
            for cell in row:
                existing_font = cell.font
                new_font = Font(bold=bold if bold is not None else existing_font.bold,
                                italic=italic if italic is not None else existing_font.italic,
                                name=font_name if font_name is not None else existing_font.name,
                                size=font_size if font_size is not None else existing_font.size,
                                color=font_color if font_color is not None else existing_font.color)
                cell.font = new_font
    
    if rows:
        if isinstance(rows, int):
            apply_font(ws.iter_rows(min_row=rows, max_row=rows))
        elif isinstance(rows, list):
            for row in rows:
                apply_font(ws.iter_rows(min_row=row, max_row=row))
    if cols:
        if isinstance(cols, int):
            apply_font(ws.iter_cols(min_col=cols, max_col=cols))
        elif isinstance(cols, list):
            for col in cols:
                apply_font(ws.iter_cols(min_col=col, max_col=col))

As suggested by @iBeMeltin I merged the two functions to give a full example.
